# O que significa "região acima da dobra"?

Tags: html, css, google, terminologia

Na pagina do [developers google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent) há varias citações 
a este termo: "Estruture seu HTML para carregar primeiramente somente o conteúdo crítico, da **região acima da dobra**"
O que seria esta região acima da dobra? qual parte do HTML seria?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Acima da dobra", ou dobra superior da página, refere-se à porção da página que os usuários podem ver sem rolar até sua parte inferior.
Este termo está, geralmente, ligado a exibição de propagandas nas páginas.

A recomendação da Google agora é que seja sempre evidenciado primeiro o conteúdo e que este ocupe o maior espaço possível junto à estrutura de layout. O mais importante é que o conteúdo apareça acima das dobras.

[image]

---

**Mas, e se eu quiser evidenciar os anúncios ao invés do conteúdo na primeira dobra? O que acontecerá?**

O Google irá *"punir"* seu site.

Seu site será mostrado num nível mais inferior nos resultados do Google, consequentemente, você terá um número de visitantes vindo dos resultados do Google menor. E, por tabela, um número menor de *pageviews*.

Mas, se o foco for apenas o resultado financeiro (quanto $/R$ o site rende), deve-se observar se é mais vantagem estar numa posição pior nas buscas e ter menos *pageviews* ou estar melhor ranqueado e ter menos anúncios.

---

[Acima da dobra](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/132618?hl=pt-BR)

[Post interessante](http://www.ferramentasblog.com/2012/02/google-esta-punindo-quem-nao-destaca-conteudo-no-blog.html) sobre posicionamento de anúncios.

Comment: Aceita esta. Esta resposta está optima!

Comment: @emanuelsn nice work =D

Answer (score 3):

"Above the fold" é o conteudo que fica à mostra sem tu teres que fazer `scroll down` ao rato; "fold" ("dobra") é o nome que se dá ao conteudo que aparece quando fazes `scroll down`