# Otimize a exibição de CSS

Tags: css

Olá gostaria de ajuda de vocês sobre como posso otimizar meu CSS já estão todos otimizados mais tem 1 em questão que não consigo remover e isso está me deixando incomodado agradeço!

[image: Otimize a exibição de CSS]

Comment: Se o arquivo css for pequeno coloque o conteúdo dele dentro de uma tag style. Em php vc faria <style> echo file_get_contents('linkdoseucss')</style>. Isso vai resolver esse problema.

Comment: O Google define que o CSS responsável pelo estilo de toda a parte visível inicial da página deveria estar incorporado junto ao HTML para otimizar seu carregamento, de forma que apenas a parte não visível do site dependa de um arquivo externo. A questão é: você está tendo problemas de performance tão graves assim? Se não, pode ignorar tal mensagem.

Comment: *Perguntas amplas geram respostas amplas.* Seja específico e forneça *todos* os dados pertinentes para a solução do problema. Veja o [tour] para  aprender melhor como funciona o Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que significa "região acima da dobra"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74359/o-que-significa-regi%c3%a3o-acima-da-dobra)

Answer (score 1):

O Google considera que a página terá maior desempenho quando considerado o tempo de carregamento quando todo o CSS responsável por estilizar a região acima da dobra esteja incorporado no HTML via tag `style`; isso porquê tal código CSS seria entregue junto com o restante do HTML ao navegador, na mesma resposta HTTP, e poderia ser analisado mais rapidamente quando comparado a um arquivo CSS externo, que é entregue em uma resposta HTTP diferente.

[O que significa "região acima da dobra"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74359/5878)

No geral, essa é uma técnica desnecessária, pois dificilmente temos tamanho problema com performance que dividindo o CSS resolveria. Na verdade, o tempo de carregamento da página fica praticamente o mesmo, o que cria é a sensação de carregar mais rápido, pois a parte visível da página carrega, de fato, antes. Pontos que geralmente inviabilizam utilizar tal técnica é que:

- dividir o código CSS acaba prejudicando a manutenção do sistema, pois você possuirá códigos de mesma natureza separados em arquivos distintos;
- além, também, que haverá a possibilidade de replicação de código: se todas as páginas do site estiverem em um mesmo layout, é provável que o código CSS responsável pela região acima da dobra seja o mesmo e mesmo assim seria necessário incluí-lo em todos os arquivos HTML;
- e também afeta diretamente o sistema de cacheamento de código, pois um código CSS incluído no HTML só será cacheado se o arquivo HTML for cacheado - e nem sempre isso é interessante: você pode ter uma página em que apenas as informações mudam, mas o CSS não, então seria interessante apenas cachear o CSS e não o HTML.

No geral, você mais ganha ignorando tal dica do que prejuízo, então acho que você pode ignorá-la sem medo.