# É uma boa prática inserir as tags do CSS no final do corpo do Body?

Tags: css, pagespeed-insights

Verifiquei a **performance** por meio de **testes** no site da **google** denominado [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=pt-BR), ao inserir as **tags** relacionadas ao `CSS` no final do corpo do `body` **sobe bastante a pontuação**.

1. Porém isto é uma boa prática?
2. Possui algum problema utilizar deste modo?

Comment: Peço por gentileza para ler arduamente sobre [como criar uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aqui na comunidade.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [A ordem dos estilos CSS influenciam a árvore de renderização?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/326990/a-ordem-dos-estilos-css-influenciam-a-%c3%a1rvore-de-renderiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS olha li este tópico que você cita como possível duplicata mas la trata da ordem das propriedades do CSS no elemento e na minha pergunta eu pergunto sobre o CSS num todo. E agradeço por me alertar sobre como criar uma boa pergunta e que acabei fazendo ela de forma bem rápida pois estava de saída.

Comment: a sua pergunta é semelhante ao link da possível duplicata. Neste mesmo link aborda o assunto de Construção, layout e gravação da árvore de renderização, onde você precisa ler afundo não somente neste link e por fora para entender os caminhos críticos de como o pagespeed-insights da google analisa a sua performance, está tudo lá. Abaixo eu deixei a minha resposta para você, indo direto ao assunto do que realmente acontece em termos técnicos, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vi esse link e achei que poderia complementar a sua dúvida https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214425/por-que-a-google-recomenda-css-inline

Answer (score 8):

Sim faz diferença, para pior, e isso está ligado a como é montada a árvore de renderização do documento. Se vc quiser saber mais sobre o assunto, essa questão pode ser um ponto de partida [A ordem dos estilos CSS influenciam a árvore de renderização?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/326990/a-ordem-dos-estilos-css-influenciam-a-%C3%A1rvore-de-renderiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Olha o que acontece quando o CSS está no final do documento
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando está no início! Repare nos MS de carregamento!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora olha como fica o Refresh quando o CSS está no final do documento.

Repare como por alguns MS vc consegue ver o HTML sem o CSS aplicado. Agora imagina isso com uma conexão lenta ou no Celular com sinal ruim....

Esse comportamente é conhecido como FOUC *(flash of unstyled content)* e está descrito até na Wikipédia rss https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Independente da organização das pastas no servido de qq forma coloca o CSS ao final do documente é uma péssima prática... O resultado fala por si só, e o PageSpeed pode ter melhorado pq o HTML tem um peso maior que o CSS para o Google, e até pq não existe SEO no CSS *(o máximo que se sabe sobre o assunto é se o site é responsivo o Google prioriza, o resto é um assunto obscuro e incerto)*

---

**Uma alternativa**

Uma opção é dividir seu CSS em pelo menos 2 partes

```
 <link href="above.css"> (20kb)
--------------------------------
 <link href="below.css"> (200kb)
```

Assim no `<head>` vc vai ter um CSS essencial ao layout que fica antes da primeira dobra *(layout que aparece antes do primeiro scroll)*, e no final do documento vc coloca o restante do CSS em uma folha separada. Isso vai acelerar o carregamento, mas sem comprometer a renderização da primeira parte.

**OBS:** e sim a tag `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" >` é permitida dentro do `<body>` pois é um `phrasing content` *(mas nem todo tipo de `<link>` é aceito dentro do body)* https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

---

Esse é o código do teste, ele foi feito com Bootstrap que tem um CSS bem extenso

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/product/product.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
    <nav class="site-header sticky-top py-1">
        <div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between">
          <a class="py-2" href="#">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="d-block mx-auto"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="14.31" y1="8" x2="20.05" y2="17.94"></line><line x1="9.69" y1="8" x2="21.17" y2="8"></line><line x1="7.38" y1="12" x2="13.12" y2="2.06"></line><line x1="9.69" y1="16" x2="3.95" y2="6.06"></line><line x1="14.31" y1="16" x2="2.83" y2="16"></line><line x1="16.62" y1="12" x2="10.88" y2="21.94"></line></svg>
          </a>
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Tour</a>
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Product</a>
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Enterprise</a>
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Support</a>
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Cart</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
  
      <div class="position-relative overflow-hidden p-3 p-md-5 m-md-3 text-center bg-light">
        <div class="col-md-5 p-lg-5 mx-auto my-5">
          <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-normal">Punny headline</h1>
          <p class="lead font-weight-normal">And an even wittier subheading to boot. Jumpstart your marketing efforts with this example based on Apple's marketing pages.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Coming soon</a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-device box-shadow d-none d-md-block"></div>
        <div class="product-device product-device-2 box-shadow d-none d-md-block"></div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
        <div class="bg-dark mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden">
          <div class="my-3 py-3">
            <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
            <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-light box-shadow mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
          <div class="my-3 p-3">
            <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
            <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-dark box-shadow mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
        <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
          <div class="my-3 p-3">
            <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
            <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-dark box-shadow mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-primary mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden">
          <div class="my-3 py-3">
            <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
            <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-light box-shadow mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
        <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
          <div class="my-3 p-3">
            <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
            <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-white box-shadow mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
          <div class="my-3 py-3">
            <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
            <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-white box-shadow mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
        <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
          <div class="my-3 p-3">
            <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
            <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-white box-shadow mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
          <div class="my-3 py-3">
            <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
            <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-white box-shadow mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <footer class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="d-block mb-2"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="14.31" y1="8" x2="20.05" y2="17.94"></line><line x1="9.69" y1="8" x2="21.17" y2="8"></line><line x1="7.38" y1="12" x2="13.12" y2="2.06"></line><line x1="9.69" y1="16" x2="3.95" y2="6.06"></line><line x1="14.31" y1="16" x2="2.83" y2="16"></line><line x1="16.62" y1="12" x2="10.88" y2="21.94"></line></svg>
            <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</small>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md">
            <h5>Features</h5>
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Cool stuff</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Random feature</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team feature</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Stuff for developers</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another one</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Last time</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md">
            <h5>Resources</h5>
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource name</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another resource</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Final resource</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md">
            <h5>Resources</h5>
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Business</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Education</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Government</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Gaming</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md">
            <h5>About</h5>
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Locations</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
              <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Terms</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
  

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vale citar que uma das partes mais críticas dentro da página (em questão de SEO e métricas no PageSpeed) é a [região acima da dobra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74359/5878). Isso justifica a pontuação no PageSpeed aumentar, pois sem o CSS carregado você diminui o tempo de renderização desta região (abrindo mão da exibição correta, como você demonstrou).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso mesmo! Ninguém sabe ao certo os critérios do Google, mas certamente o conteúdo "acima da dobra" tem uma importância especial. Boa dica!

Answer (score 1):

**Árvore de Renderização**

> As **árvores** do **CSSOM** e do **DOM** são combinadas em uma ***árvore de renderização***, que é usada para processar o layout de cada elemento visível e atua como mecanismo de entrada para o processo de gravação, que renderiza os pixels na tela. A otimização de cada uma dessas etapas é essencial para se obter o desempenho de renderização ideal. No entanto, ambos são objetos independentes que capturam aspectos diferentes do documento: um descreve o conteúdo e o outro, as regras de estilo que devem ser aplicadas ao documento. Como podemos mesclar os dois para que o navegador renderize os pixels na tela?

**Exemplo ilustrativo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**As etapas do navegador para Processar e Renderizar são as seguintes:**

> **1)** Processar a marcação HTML e criar a árvore do DOM.
>
> **2)** Processar a marcação CSS e criar a árvore do CSSOM.
>
> **3)** Combinar o DOM e o CSSOM em uma árvore de renderização.
>
> **4)** Executar o layout na árvore de renderização para calcular a geometria de cada nó.
>
> **5)** Pintar os nós individuais na tela.

Então sabendo disto tudo..

**Não.. Não há consequências mediante a ordenação aleatória de propriedades CSS.** Contudo, ***mesmo que não afete a performance do projeto de forma significativa*** deve-se atentar a organização da arquitetura do projeto em relação as pastas e em relação ao **HTML** inserir cada **tag** no seu devido lugar, isto se chama boas práticas e design patterns.

**Parte do conteúdo** foi retirado desta [FONTE...](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=pt)

Comment: Seria legal incluir a fonte na resposta