# css funcionando diferente - dentro da tag ou em arquivo separado .css

Tags: html, css, html-tags, style

Montei um arquivo básico com um menu simples. simplifiquei-o ao máximo para tentar encontrar o problema e não consigo.

O problema é que, ao entrar no site, a animação especificada na **transition** do css começa a funcionar automaticamente, ampliando os botões e alterando suas cores, mas apenas quando importo o arquivo .css
Se eu uso a tag  para inserir o css, a animação não funciona a menos que o cursor sobreponha o botão.

Abaixo com todo o conteúdo junto, funcionando como eu preciso, apenas com o :hover

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.escolha{background-color: #999; color: #fff;}
.escolha ul { list-style: none; margin-left: -40px;}
.escolha ul li {background-color: #999; padding: 10px 0; cursor: pointer;  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}
.escolha ul li estado{width: 50%; padding: 10px; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}
.escolha ul li cidade{width: 50%; padding: 10px; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}
.escolha ul li:hover {background-color: #6ab4c6; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}
.escolha ul li:hover estado{background-color: #0088a4;}
.escolha ul li:hover cidade{padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;}`
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="escolha">
    <ul>
        <li><estado>SP</estado><cidade>São Paulo</cidade></li>
        <li><estado>SP</estado><cidade>São Caetano</cidade></li>
        <li><estado>PR</estado><cidade>Curitiba</cidade></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Abaixo com os arquivos separados, importando o .css, onde a animação acontece

```css
.escolha{background-color: #999; color: #fff;}
.escolha ul { list-style: none; margin-left: -40px;}
.escolha ul li {background-color: #999; padding: 10px 0; cursor: pointer;  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}
.escolha ul li estado{width: 50%; padding: 10px; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}
.escolha ul li cidade{width: 50%; padding: 10px; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}
.escolha ul li:hover {background-color: #6ab4c6; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}
.escolha ul li:hover estado{background-color: #0088a4;}
.escolha ul li:hover cidade{padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylepaginas.css" media="screen, handheld" />

</head>

<body>
<div class="escolha">
    <ul>
        <li><estado>SP</estado><cidade>São Paulo</cidade></li>
        <li><estado>SP</estado><cidade>São Caetano</cidade></li>
        <li><estado>PR</estado><cidade>Curitiba</cidade></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Tentei utilizar o jsfiddle para testar mas o erro não acontece, apenas no localhost e na versão online.

Se alguém tiver uma solução, eu agradecerei muito.

Comment: Cara da forma como vc explicou não deu para entender o problema... testando sei código aqui quando a pagina carrega nada acontece, mas quando coloca o mouse a animação funciona normalmente... qual é o problema de fato?

Comment: O problema é que, na versão que importa o css, os botões simplesmente se animam sozinhos, sem ocorrer o hover. É como se eles não tivessem qualquer especificação e, após importar o css, eles crescem e adquirem as cores corretas. 
Consegui me explicar???

Comment: testei dos dois modos aqui e o funcionamento foi o mesmo, ou seja, as animações só funcionam no hover, como deve ser.

Comment: @VaralStudio e qual é o modo correto que deveria ser o funcionamento? Explica melhor...

Comment: Deveria funcionar apenas com o hover. Quando uso o import funciona mais ou menos assim: Os botões aparecem sem qualquer formatação, apenas texto em preto e sem fundo e simplesmente crescem até ficarem nos formatos finais, com fundo cinza e texto em branco. Esse "crescer" que não era para acontecer. Não sei se posso colocar link para o site onde fiz o teste...

Comment: Ou vc está importando o .CSS errado ou o .CSS que vc está importando tem outros Estilos e propriedades que estão atrapalhando o CSS que vc apresentou aqui.

Comment: Pensei nessa possibilidade, por isso apaguei todas as outras informações e deixei apenas o que importava. Fiz uns testes aqui e descobri que é um problema exclusivo do Chrome, seja no Windows, MAC ou android.

Comment: Se não for apagado o link, segue:
http://varalstudio.com.br/teste/teste1.php
Todas as vezes que atualizo, a animação acontece novamente.

Comment: Já esse abaixo funciona:
http://varalstudio.com.br/teste/teste2.php
Nesse o css está dentro da tag <style>

Comment: Essa linha me parece errado o transition normalmente é fora do Hover, remova o transition aaqui e teste `.escolha ul li:hover {background-color: #6ab4c6; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;}` tira o transition: all 0.5s ease 0s dessa classe

Comment: O erro persiste. Chegou a testar os link? Apareceu o que eu estou tentando explicar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode parece doidera, mas não sei porque só consegui resolver o "bug" colocando o link do CSS dentro do `<body>`. E Sim é permitido colocar o CSS dentro do Body como vc pode ver aqui [É uma boa prática inserir as tags do CSS no final do corpo do Body?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382657/%C3%89-uma-boa-pr%C3%A1tica-inserir-as-tags-do-css-no-final-do-corpo-do-body/382676#382676)

Veja o código do Gif e quando eu dou o refresh etc. No Chrome resolveu, e no FireFox parece não acontecer o problema.

Em suma seu HTML tem que ficar dessa forma para evitar o Bug

```html
.....
</head>

<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylepaginas.css" media="screen, handheld" />

<div class="escolha">
    <ul>
        <li><estado>SP</estado><cidade>São Paulo</cidade></li>
        <li><estado>SP</estado><cidade>São Caetano</cidade></li>
        <li><estado>PR</estado><cidade>Curitiba</cidade></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
.....
```

Comment: Doideira mesmo. O problema desaparece. Nesse caso é uma solução que vou utilizar, mas fico pensando se, com uma programação mais complexa, seria viável.
Valeu, hugocsl....

Comment: @VaralStudio eu não conseguiu outra solução que resolvesse o problema... E estranhamente em um projeto maior pode ser que não ocorra isso, pois parece não haver motivo certo para o ocorrido.... Não que eu tenha identificado. Se vc acha que resolveu o problema lembre-se de marcar esse ícone ´✔´ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da minha resposta. Vc pode remove-lo depois caso apareça outra resposta que vc julgue mais completa

Comment: Obrigado.
Não sabia sobre o ´✔´ .

Comment: @VaralStudio eh uma forma de manter o site organizado, e mesmo com uma resposta aceita outra pessoa pode responder tbm, uma coisa não impede a outra. Mas assim a pergunta não fica em ordem via com sem resposta aceita mesmo na tendo sido resolvido. Vlw a força

Comment: Eu quem agradeço. Sempre usei o site mas buscando pelas perguntas e respostas de outros. Nunca tinha acontecido de precisar perguntar diretamente, por isso não tinha percebido o funcionamento completo do site.