# Como fazer para a "transition" em CSS não ocorrer quando a página é atualizada?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Andei criando algumas transição em alguns projetos e acabei notando que a transição ocorre quando a página é carregada ou atualizada. Tenho este exemplo em que a transição é para ocorrer apenas quando eu passar o mouse sobre a `div`, e ele muda a cor com uma transição mais suave, mas a transição é aplicada também quando a página é carregada.

```css
div{
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: background-color 2s;
}

div:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Parece um efeito de opacidade e depois volta a cor normal. Isso ocorre apenas com o **Chrome** e **Opera**, pois testei no **Firefox**, **Edge**, **IE11** e o efeito não acontece no **stackoverflow** creio que não vai dar para vocês notarem, terão que criar um arquivo html, Mas existe algum meio para parar de acontecer isso? seja em código ou no browser?

Comment: Eu não consigo afirmar ao certo, mas esse parece um comportamento arbritário do Chrome... da uma olhada nessa questão e veja a minha resposta como resolveu. Se funcionar para vc. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383494/css-funcionando-diferente-dentro-da-tag-ou-em-arquivo-separado-css inclusive tb te indico resetar a máquina, pois talvez isso possa ser questão de hardware e gerenciamento de memória ou sei lá. Vale testar... aqui eu testei com o seu código hoje e não tive problemas funcionou normal como o esperado, só ativa o transitio no :hover e não no refresh

Comment: Não, funcionou deve ser normal do chrome e opera acontecer isso, Mas isso afeta os projetos que nós criamos, não deveria ocorrer isso.

Comment: Eu só notei isso depois da última atualização do Chrome. Porém atualmente não acontece mais comigo, na época resolvi com a resposta que dei na pergunta do link que comentei acima

Comment: Era para ser um sim lá em cima escrevi errado. Eu testei o código e a animação acontece antes do hover, era bem isso mesmo parecido com o meu problema e testei aqui o problema foi solucionado mas porque isso ocorre é um bug mesmo ou não?

Comment: Jovem, marquei como duplicada pq a outra resposta/pergunta parecem resolver o problema como eu suspeitava. Infelizmente não sei te dizer pq isso está acontecendo.Pode ser problema individual da sua máquina, ou pode ser geral (não acredito que seja) ou então é problema de versão do browser, que acredito ser o mais provável, apesar de não poder afirmar.... Eu só consigo te dizer como resolver, mas não posso te afirma pq isso está acontecendo...

Comment: Há mais ok, o importante é que você me ajudou e solucionou o problema obrigado hugocsi

Answer (score -1):

Para funcionar em nos navegadores citados.

```
div{
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    webkit-transition: background-color 2s; /* Para Google 
    Chrome anterior a 26.0 e para Safari 3.0 ~ 6.0*/
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s; /*Para Mozilla 
     anterior 16.0 */
     -o-transition: background-color 2s; /* Para Opera 
     anterior 12.1 */
    transition: background-color 2s;
}

div:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Tem **ANOS** que já não é mais preciso colocar prefixo de browser na propriedade transition http://prntscr.com/nsihrp fonte https://caniuse.com/#search=transition o problema é outro...

Comment: A propriedade "transition" já é suportada pela verão mais recente do Chrome e Opera, não é necessário utilizar prefixo. A transição ocorre mas antes dela ocorrer acontece um efeito de opacidade que não era para acontecer.

Answer (score -1):

Por existirem muitos navegadores, e cada um com sua especificação, é necessário adicionar esses prefixos para que um estilo CSS funcione em todos.
Assim temos que:

```
-webkit-
```

(Chrome, Safari, versões mais recentes do Opera.)

```
-moz-
```

(Firefox)

```
-o-
```

(Versões antigas do Opera)

```
-ms-
```

(Internet Explorer)

[Link de Referência da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Prefixos_vendor)

Comment: Valeu colega, Mas não é esse o problema a propriedade "transition" funciona em todos os navegadores o problema é que quando a página é atualizada o browser adiciona opacidade automaticamente e depois volta ao estado normal.