# Problemas com a transição no css

Tags: html, css

Eu estava estudando a questão da transição e me deparei com um problema: se eu colocar a transição com seus devidos parâmetros dentro da minha classe no CSS tudo que eu declarei dentro dela é ativado com a transição por exemplo a margin-top, ela não é ativada assim que a pagina é carregada mas sim com uma transição mas se eu colocar na minha classe com a pseudoclasse :hover inicialmente tudo fica certo mas quando eu tiro o mouse ocorre uma "transição bruta" já que o para a transição ocorrer é necessario que o mouse fique sobre o local, o que devo fazer para a transição ocorrer nos conformes sem causar nenhuma interferência com o meu codigo?

com essses arquivos já dá pra ver oq quero dizer

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
}

.teste{
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 background: linear-gradient(#DCDCDC,#808080);
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 120px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 150px;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
 transition: 2s;
}

.teste:hover{
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 line-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>aulas</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="teste">
  <h3>um titulo qualquer</h3>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo seu seu código não da para  te ajudar. Clique em Editar e incluia o seu CSS e HTML

Comment: Vc quer que o botão fique aumentando e diminuindo o tempo inteiro, mesmo sem precisar fazer o :hover é isso??

Comment: Não exatamente, acontece que a minha div tem margin-top de 120px, isso já foi declarado mas ao invés da pagina já carregar ela com essa margem ocorre uma transição entende? quando a pagina é carregada aqui, a div é gerada do zero e desliza desde margin-top 0 até margin-top 120px

Comment: Nas ultimas atualizações do chrome eu vi alguns relatos desse tipo de problema, nessa Pergunta vc pode ver mais, leia inclusive os comentários pois acredito que eh o seu problema ai https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383494/css-funcionando-diferente-dentro-da-tag-ou-em-arquivo-separado-css