# Esconder botão do editor de texto kendoUI

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui

Estou utilizando o [editor de texto do kendoUI](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/editor/)

Eu preciso retirar o último botão do editor (inserir imagem).

A tag renderizada é o último , que possui dentro o button de imagem.

Eu tentei algo como:

```
kendo-toolbar-renderer:last-of-type{
    display: none!important;
}
```

Também tentei:

```
kendo-toolbar-renderer:last-child{
    display: none!important;
}
```

Porém ainda continua aparecendo o botão no editor, alguma alternativa?

Comment: Segundo a documentação vc pode adicionar ou remover os botões que vc quiser 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubevvv?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Com JS vc consegue remover na _força bruta_: `var kendobts = document.querySelectorAll("kendo-toolbar-renderer");
kendobts[kendobts.length-1].outerHTML = '';`

Comment: Ou tente isso no CSS: `kendo-toolbar-renderer:last-child{
   display: none !important;
}`

Answer (score 1):

A regra CSS que está lá na verdade é essa, porém repare que ele colocam um `display:inline-block` direto na tag sobrescrevendo o que está no CSS. O que eu te indico é fazer um regra mais forte tipo

```
.kendo-toolbar.k-toolbar .kendo-toolbar-renderer:last-of-type{
    display: none !important;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se isso não der certo um artifício é colocar o CSS depois que o JS for carregado para isso vc vai ter que colocar lá no final do documento como última tag antes do fechamento do `</body>` uma tag `<style>` para testar se assim esse CSS vai sobrescrever o que foi renderizado antes.

Ficaria algo como isso...

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>

    <style>
        .kendo-toolbar.k-toolbar .kendo-toolbar-renderer:last-of-type {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém existe um efeito colateral de colocar o CSS no final do documento que vc pode ler nessa outra questão [É uma boa prática inserir as tags do CSS no final do corpo do Body?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382657/%c3%89-uma-boa-pr%c3%a1tica-inserir-as-tags-do-css-no-final-do-corpo-do-body/382676#382676)

Comment: Tentei no css global e no index.html, continua aparecendo.

Comment: Tenta colocar isso no css e ve se o ícone some `[title="Insert image"] {
            display: none !important;
        }`

Comment: Não deu certo, de qualquer forma eu precisaria que sumisse o botão pois eu queria que não utilizasse essa propriedade

Comment: @VeroneseComS na verdade era só um teste para ver se funcionaria no filho e não no pai. Mas se mesmo assim o CSS não pegou fica complicado.... Acho que eu não consigo te ajudar com muito mais que isso :/

Comment: obrigado de qualquer forma, se eu conseguir posto aqui

Comment: @VeroneseComS se conseguir posta ai, pode ser que uma função com document.ready vc consiga por a propriedade depois fazendo a sobreposição da classe em um setTimeout